# how to uninstall "Page Inspector" from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How to uninstall "Page Inspector" from Visual Studio 2010.

It seems like Page Inspector is the culprit for the following while running MVC3 application

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Runtime, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/92823976-be85-43af-9efa-6b28f441fd6b

Comment: How silly, figured it out: Control Panel-> add and remove ->microsoft page inspectator ->click uninstall

Answer (score 2):

Instead you may try disable PageInspector just for one project. Put to `web.config`:

```xml
<appSettings>
  <add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to control panel Remove Program >> Find Microsoft Page Inspector >> Uninstall it

Comment: whats the problem in that ? its the only solution